# Converting a rewrite from htaccess to nginx

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm currently using this htaccess code in `Apache` to change the `URL` in address bar from `http://www.domain.com/list?m=100` to `http://www.domain.com/list/100`

```
RewriteEngine On

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ index.php?m=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The above htaccess is on `/list` directory.

I have tried to convert it to `nginx` (using http://winginx.com/en/htaccess), but I couldn't make it work. This is what I tried

```
location /list/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/([^.]*)$ /index.php?m=$1 break;
    }
}
```

The above just downloads the `PHP` code. I also tried changing the break to last, but it just opens the homepage (the url in the address bar changes to `http://www.domain.com/list/100`). Any suggestions how I can make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert everything, use this:

```
location /list/ {
   rewrite ^/list/(.*)$ /index.php?m=$1 last;
}
```

Don't forget to restart nginx afterwards to see the changes.

Comment: For integer values i prefer `[0-9]` or `\d` then accepting all with `.*` .

Comment: Not working. It's still just showing the homepage instead. It also works if I try `http://www.domain.com/list?m=100` without adding the code to `sites-available/default`

Comment: So your file is in www.domain.com/list.php or it's located in a directory called list? such as /var/www/html/list/?

From the above link, it looks like it's /var/www/html/index.php.

Comment: It actually is `index.php` on `/usr/share/nginx/html/list/`.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to rewrite ^/list/(.*)$ /list/index.php?m=$1 last; and now it is working.